# Converting a range output to "1,2,3,4,5,6" and excluding output numbers

Tags: php

Hi I need to convert the natural output from a range to a list of numbers separated with commas and exclude some output numbers

```
foreach (range(0, $clpyrdesde, 2) as $numero) {
    echo $numero;
}
```

If $clepydesde was "18" the output was "024681012141618" I need this numbers like "0,2,4,6..." and excluding the "0", so results needs to be "2,4,6..."

Comment: Why do you have `"$clpyrdesde"` instead of just `$clpyrdesde`?

Comment: I tried to do some things and I forgot to remove it

Comment: If you want the range to start at 2, why not start the range at 2? `range(2, 18, 2) `

Answer (score 1):

You're echoing them individually with no separators, so add those:

```
implode(',', range(0, $clpyrdesde, 2));
```

This is what [`implode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is for specifically.

Comment: Change the 0 to 2 if you don't want the zero at the beginning. There's no need to put numbers in quotes.

Comment: @miknik Those were in the original question, but I've removed them since you're right, it's silly.

Comment: Yeah you beat me to it with an answer so my comment was more for the OPs benefit really. You look like you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

[Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the range from 2 to $clprdesde

```
<?php
        $clpyrdesde = 18;
        echo implode(',' , range('2', $clpyrdesde, '2'));
?>
```

Comment: how can I get 1 of the range numbers randomly?